# How to sort a list of mixed integers / fractions in pari/gp

Tags: list, sorting, pari-gp

Currently I'm implementing an algorithm to return the Farey Series of order n by calling my function with FareySeries(n). This works quite well,for example calling
`L = FareySeries(4)`
returns
`List([0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 3/4])`
but I need the list to be sorted. Reading the documentation, I thought

```
listsort(L)
```

would do the job, but it seems this only works for Integers and Floats (I tested this manually). Is there some built-in function(or parameter) for sorting a list containing mixed integers and fractions or do I have to sort it manually?
I don't need code to sort for myself, I just want to use, what has already been implemented; sticking to the basics of coding here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest workaround is to use `vecsort`. In general I would recommend always using vectors over lists except when incrementally building up a list. After constructing a list, it is cleaner to return it from a function as a vector.

```
L = List([0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 3/4]);
listsort(L);
L
```

gives: `List([0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 3/4])` (incorrect)

```
L = List([0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 3/4]);
vecsort(L)
```

gives: `List([0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1])` (correct)

Note that `vecsort` does not modify the original list, so if you want to update the list then you need to assign the output of `vecsort` back to the variable.

However, I would recommend using vectors.

```
L = Vec(List([0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 3/4]));
vecsort(L)
```

gives: `[0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1]` (note the absence of `List`).

The underlying reason for this is that `vecsort` uses `lex`, but `listsort` uses `cmp`. I am not sure why `cmp` is so badly behaved - could be a bug, but more likely broken by design.

It seems that `listsort` sorts in the same order as used by sets and is optimized for performance rather than user expectation. If you wish to use `setsearch` on your list then you need to have it ordered as for sets. There is also a function `vecsearch` that uses `lex` as a comparison function.

It is perhaps also worth mentioning that both `vecsort` and `vecsearch` take as an optional argument a user supplied comparison function.